# Parsing a file in backward and forward direction

Tags: bash, parsing, sed, grep

I have a very long file with a periodical structure (the three dots resembles numbers of lines not necessarily equal, and n is just an index):

```
...
string bar text1 (n-2)
...
string bar text1 (n-1)
...
string bar text1 (n)
...
STRING FOO
elements1
elements1
...
string bar text2 (n-2)
...
string bar text2 (n-1)
...
string bar text2 (n)
...
STRING FOO
elements2
elements2
...
```

I am trying to make a bash script to parse this file, and print to another file the following information: find all the appearances of `STRING FOO` and print to the new file the `elements` (which can be two, for example) plus the `string bar n`. In order to achieve that, I have tried the following commands:

```
grep -A 2 "STRING FOO"  input_file.txt   >> output_file.txt
grep -B 200 "STRING FOO" input_file.txt | tac | sed -n '/'string bar n'/ { p ; q }' >> output_file.txt
```

Expected output:

```
STRING FOO
elements1
elements1
string bar text1
STRING FOO
elements2
elements2
string bar text2
```

Where the number 200 is just a "guess" of how many lines I need to go back. Those commands, besides inefficient, are not working properly. I would really appreciate someone else's help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With :

```
grep "STRING FOO\|string bar" file.out | grep -B 1 STRING FOO | head -n 1
```

You will have your `"string bar text1 (n)"`

And repeat the same logic for your "elements".

Sincerely.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this all in one *gung-ho* `Awk` command, for this,

```
awk '/string bar/{ pat=$0; }/\<STRING FOO\>/{c=NR+2}(NR<=c){print}(NR==c){print pat}' file
```

which outputs only the lines below as you needed,

```
STRING FOO
elements1
elements1
string bar text1 (n)
STRING FOO
elements2
elements2
string bar text2 (n)
```

Comment: from OP's usage, seems `string bar n` is not entire line and is appended after the three lines starting from `STRING FOO`

Comment: something like `awk '/string bar n/{s=$0} /STRING FOO/{print $0; f=1; c=2; next} f && c--; f && c==0{print s; f=0}' file`

Comment: @Sundeep: Appreciate the attempt, will leave it OP which matches his  actual requirement

Comment: @Sundeep: But I would suggest a whole string match on your example though, like in my answer:)

Comment: my take is that if that string is constant, OP wouldn't have to bother with second command of grep+tac+sed

Comment: Hi @Inian. Thanks a lot for the answer! But I am afraid I wasn't so clear: string bar n is the same as string bar n-1 and so on , i.e. the n is just an index. I will edit the question.

Comment: @Panadestein: Answer updated to your actual requirement!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -n '/string bar/h;/STRING FOO/{N;N;x;H;g;p}' in.txt
```

Output:

```
STRING FOO
elements1
elements1
string bar text1 (n)
STRING FOO
elements2
elements2
string bar text2 (n)
```

1. sed flag `-n` mean "do not print output by default. Printing can be done by command `p`.
2. `/string bar/h` - when found string "string bar", hold(command `h`) it in hold buffer.
3. `/STRING FOO/{ .. }` - when found string "STRING FOO" execute commands inside brackets.
4. `N;N` - append next (command `N`) two line to current one (i.e. "STRING FOO" + two lines "elements").
5. `x` - exchange hold and pattern buffer. Now in hold buffer 3 lines with "STRING FOO" and two with "elements".
   And in current pattern buffer "string bar".
6. `H` - append current lines to hold buffer.
7. `g` - get strings from hold buffer to current pattern space.
8. `p` - print lines from current pattern space.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works but only one time, and the structure of the file repeats periodically a certain number of times, and I want all of them.

Comment: @Panadestein you can make that clear by adding expected output explicitly to the question by modifying the input to include at least two such structures...

Comment: @Sundeep, you were totally right, it wasn't clear. I hope now it  is.

Comment: @Panadestein, i fix answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer @komar it also works!

Comment: Can I redirect the sed output to a file with >> out.txt?

Comment: Sure. Or, if you want fix it directly in file, you can add flag `-i` to sed.